# How to print incremental count of occurrences of unique values in column 1

Tags: awk, perl

I'm trying to come up with an solution to this problem, I need to incrementally count and then print the counts of the unique values in column 1 of a tab delimited text file.  Here is an example:

> ```
> Apple_1   1      300
> Apple_2   1      500
> Apple_2   500    1500
> Apple_2   1500   2450
> Apple_3   1      1250
> Apple_3   1250   2000
> ```

And the desired output is:

> ```
> Apple_1   1      300     1
> Apple_2   1      500     1
> Apple_2   500    1500    2
> Apple_2   1500   2450    3
> Apple_3   1      1250    1
> Apple_3   1250   2000    2
> ```

I know that I can print the line number in awk with just print NR, but I don't know how to reset it for each unique value of column 1.

Thanks for any help you can offer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard trick for this kind of problem in Awk is to use an associative counter array:

```
awk '{ print $0 "\t" ++count[$1] }'
```

This counts the number of times the first word in each line has been seen. It's not quite what you're asking for, since

```
Apple_1   1      300
Apple_2   1      500
Apple_1   500    1500
```

would produce

```
Apple_1   1      300     1
Apple_2   1      500     1
Apple_1   500    1500    2
```

(the count for `Apple_1` isn't reset when we see `Apple_2`), but if the input is sorted you'll be OK.

Otherwise you'd need to track a counter and last-seen key:

```
awk '{ if (word == $1) { counter++ } else { counter = 1; word = $1 }; print $0 "\t" counter }'
```

Answer (score 3):

**This answer doesn't give the exact output you specified,** but may be of even greater interest to other users.

---

If you don't need *incremental* counts, but just counts of each unique value, you could use the simpler:

```
cut -f1 file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

(Note that `cut` depends on tab delimiters, not just any whitespace.)

---

Actually, since your file is already sorted on the first field, you don't need to sort it:

```
cut -f1 file.txt | uniq -c
```

And if you want to include these in the original file as a new, fourth column, you can use `join`:

```
cut -f1 file.txt | uniq -c | join -2 2 file.txt -
```

(`join` depends on sorted input.)

Output on the input provided is:

```
Apple_1 1 300 1
Apple_2 1 500 3
Apple_2 500 1500 3
Apple_2 1500 2450 3
Apple_3 1 1250 2
Apple_3 1250 2000 2
```

Note that `join` reads whitespace delimiters in an intuitive manner whether tabs or spaces, but outputs exactly one space for a delimiter.  If you want your tabs back, pipe to `tr ' ' '\t'`