# Remove lines with duplicated less than 5

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a data looks like this, for each SNP, it should repeat 5 times with different beta. But for SNP rs11704961, it only repeat twice, so I want to delete SNP rows that repeat less than 5 times. I tried to use `sort -k 1 | uniq -c`, but it considers the whole line for checking duplicates, not the first column.

```
SNP R K BETA 
rs767249 1 1 0.1065 
 rs767249 1 2 -0.007243 
 rs767249 1 3 0.02771 
 rs767249 1 4 -0.008233 
 rs767249 1 5 0.05073 
 rs11704961 2 1 0.2245 
 rs11704961 2 2 0.009203 
 rs1041894 3 1 0.1238 
 rs1041894 3 2 0.002522 
 rs1041894 3 3 0.01175
 rs1041894 3 4 -0.01122 
 rs1041894 3 5 -0.009195
```

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions on this site; I expect there is an exact duplicate somewhere but in the meantime [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188257/135943) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277365/135943) may help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) which is `awk`-like but handles the header lines intrinsically:

```
$ cat snp.mlr
@records[$SNP][NR] = $*; # retain records
@counts[$SNP] += 1;

end { # conditionally emit
  for (snp in @records) {
    if (@counts[snp] == 5) {
      emit @records[snp];
    }
  }
}

$ mlr --csvlite --fs space put -q -f snp.mlr snp.dat
SNP R K BETA
rs767249 1 1 0.1065
rs767249 1 2 -0.007243
rs767249 1 3 0.02771
rs767249 1 4 -0.008233
rs767249 1 5 0.05073
rs1041894 3 1 0.1238
rs1041894 3 2 0.002522
rs1041894 3 3 0.01175
rs1041894 3 4 -0.01122
rs1041894 3 5 -0.009195
```

Note this uses features new since the [latest 4.5.0 release](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0).

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat snp.awk
NR == 1 { # header line
  print $0
}
NR > 1 { # data line
  snp = $1;
  retain[snp][NR] = $0;
  counts[snp]++;
}
END {
  for (snp in retain) {
    if (counts[snp] == 5) {
      for (i in retain[snp]) {
        print retain[snp][i];
      }
    }
  }
}

$ awk -f snp.awk snp.dat
SNP R K BETA
rs1041894 3 1 0.1238
rs1041894 3 2 0.002522
rs1041894 3 3 0.01175
rs1041894 3 4 -0.01122
rs1041894 3 5 -0.009195
rs767249 1 1 0.1065
rs767249 1 2 -0.007243
rs767249 1 3 0.02771
rs767249 1 4 -0.008233
rs767249 1 5 0.05073
```

but note that `awk` arrays don't preserve insertion order so in this case your outputs aren't in the same order as they were in the input.